# Can I make offline mobile application using Django Rest Framework and React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, django-rest-framework, mobile-application

I want to build a working mobile app for practice and share it with my friends. I am currently learning React Native for front-end and Django Rest Framework for back-end. Now, how can I use it on my phone? Where does it store its data locally on mobile device? According to what I watched React Native needs my ip address to connect with Django Rest Framework.

For more context this will be the app's features:
Notepad
Saving notes
Recently Deleted

Where will be the saved notes be stored? Do i need to fetch all users ip address?

I really need some help, Thank you so much in advance!